# Why is php://input rejecting my large file uploads?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, file-upload

I've been turing the internet upside down in order to get chunked large file uploads to work for my Symfony2 application. In order to simplify things I've made a test program seperate from the rest of my application. The only thing it does is trying to test if php://input can accept my large file upload with the method described in this article:

http://www.webiny.com/blog/2012/05/07/webiny-file-upload-with-html5-and-ajax-using-php-streams/

The way I understand it is that if a user uploads a large video file 2GB+ then that would take 2GB+ RAM on the server and the method in the article cuts it down to 4096 bit per concurrent uploader. (I am unsure how i would test RAM usage on localhost server)

However when i try to upload large files the browser just waits a second and two and then posts a 1kb videofile.

I have set high values for php.ini settings.

Here is the relevant part of the PHP code:

```
     public function lastoppAction(Request $request)
{

    $videofilename = (string)$request->request->get("filnavn");
    $inputHandler = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $fileHandler = fopen("videoer\\myfile.tmp", "wb") or die('fopen failed');;

    while(true) {
$buffer = fgets($inputHandler, 4096);
if (strlen($buffer) == 0) {

    fclose($inputHandler);
    fclose($fileHandler);
            break;
}
fwrite($fileHandler, $buffer) or die('fwrite failed');;
    }
     $url = $this->generateUrl('largefile_navngi', array('filnavn' => $videofilename));
     return $this->redirect($url);
}
public function navngiAction(Request $request)
{
        $filnavn = $request->query->get('filnavn');
        $sti = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
        $websti = preg_replace('/app/','web',$sti,1);
        print_r("Filnavn: " . $filnavn);
        rename($websti . "/videoer/myfile.tmp",$websti . "/videoer/" . $filnavn);
        $url = $this->generateUrl('largefile_index');
        return $this->redirect($url);
}
```

The reason for the redirects is in order for rename to properly recieve the filename variable.

The AJAX code is like in the article linked above but with the following difference:

xhr.open("POST", url, false); 
Using my own localhost url. I have also tried with true here. Difference being that it works with small files if we have false in the third argument.

With async true it seems to only ever give two files the original myfile.tmp that i fopen to and a 0kb file it renames to. "filename.mp4".

What is strange is that when the ajax code runs:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(xhr.readyState == 4)
                    {
                        if(xhr.status == 200)
                        {
                            //alert("success");// process success
                                                            alert("Filnavn: " + filnavn);
                        }else{
                            // process error
                                                            alert("Status: " + xhr.status);
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Status becomes 500 even when small files like 16 MB are fully uploaded without other issues.

Here is the twig file:

```
    <h1>Test av å laste opp større filer</h1>
    <form method="post" action="{{path('largefile_lastopp')}}">
        <label>Fil: </label>
        <input type="file" name="fil" id="video" /><br /><br />
         <input type="hidden" name="filnavn" id="filnavn" />
         <input type="hidden" name="mimetype" id="mimetype" />

        <input onclick="upload('video',0)" type="submit" name="submit" />

    </form>
     ::1 - - [10/Jun/2015:15:41:36 +0200] "POST /LargeFileUpload/web/app_dev.php/lastopp HTTP/1.1" 302 436 "http://localhost/LargeFileUpload/web/app_dev.php/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Probably the server is configured for `MAX POST SIZE` below the desired size.

Comment: I think you are mixing standard file upload with another way in the article. Look at articles html. It's quite different

Comment: I have a large MAX POST SIZE

Comment: You already configure `upload_max_filesize` ?

Comment: @Paulius S. upload_max_filesize=2000M

Comment: @Stian what are logs saying?

Comment: @Stian If status code is 500, there should be some records in logs files..

Comment: @xurshid29 You mean like GET /LargeFileUpload/web/app_dev.php/navngi?filnavn= HTTP/1.1" 500           in apache Access log?

Comment: @Stian no, you should look at error logs, such as `app/logs/dev.log`, `app/logs/prod.log`, even in `/var/log/` folder..

Comment: I am not sure how to read these loggings but "POST /LargeFileUpload/web/app_dev.php/lastopp HTTP/1.1" 302 436      does this mean that there was a 302 error with errorcode 436?

Comment: Found out how log file syntax works so never mind that. There is a 302 error on the POST so presumably thats what's blocking the file. The 500 error is with regard to filename being empty it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the client code reads the whole file at once, then creates a blob from it. If you try to upload a 1GB file, that means that the browser requires at least 2GB RAM before ist sends the first byte.

I could imagine that there might be security measure that prevent this kind of memory (ab-)use.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I find it odd that there is no error message if a security measure is preventing something. Could I find an error message in some sort of log file or with different error settings if that were the case?

Comment: Not sure; depends on the browser and client OS. I would try to add some log statements (or breakpoints, if you have a browser with debugging capabilities) to the client side code to see what's happening there.

Comment: That is not easy to do with the proposed code. You would have to send multiple requests, and the server would have to reconstruct the pieces in the right order. The FileReader API does not support partial reading of files, as far as I know.